# difference between didn't and doesn't

Tags: meaning, tense

> He is perhaps the most prominent non-fiction author of our
> generation. It **doesn’t** hurt that several of his very good books have
> been turned into very good movies, including *The Big Short* and *The
> Blind Side*.

> It **didn't** hurt that she has been strategic about marketing herself and
> the firm through the media.

I wonder what the difference in meaning between **doesn't** and **didn't** is in the above contexts.

Comment: @Bodrov: That's a false distinction. *I **did** not go* is correct, but so is *I **do** not go*. The difference is that the negated past version normally denies having gone *on a single specific occasion*, whereas the negated present tense version normally denies *ever* going (past, present, or future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's simply no scope for any difference in meaning in the cited example. The subject ***is*** a prominent author, but achieving that ***current*** status obviously depended on things done in the ***past***, so both time-frames are relevant. *Present = simplest = best,* though, IMHO.

But note that *syntactically* speaking, if ***doesn't*** is changed to Past Tense ***didn't*** then we should also change Present Perfect ***has been*** to Simple Past ***were*** (OR Past Perfect ***had been***, but I personally wouldn't make that choice).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is tense. "Does" is the present tense of the verb *to do*; "did" is preterit.

You would say something "didn't hurt" if you were speaking about a specific event in the past.

> **Example:** *I got the vaccination and it didn't hurt.*

You would say something "doesn't hurt" if you want to say that this particular thing *never* hurts.

> **Example:** *You should get the vaccination, it doesn't hurt.*